# Analogous $H^1$-space for pseudo inner products

Tags: sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations, semi-riemannian-geometry

Perhaps this is a naive question but I could not find anything related to this.

Imagine we are on a bounded and regular open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^3_1$, i.e, $\mathbb{R}^4$ is considered with a Lorentzian inner product, let's say $ds^2 = -dx_1^2 + \sum_{i=1}^3dx_i^2.$

In this setting, is it possible to define analogously $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ with inner product
$$-\int_{\Omega}(u')^2 + \int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2?$$

If it is possible, is there analogous Poincaré inequality and Kondrakov immersion theorem's?

Comment: What would be the point? This is not even a norm, as you can easily take any function $u(t,x)=u_1(t)+u_2(x)$ with $\int |u'|^2-\int |\nabla u|^2=0$ but of course $u\not\equiv cst$. I mean, sure, this particular difference can arise somewhere as just a particular functional (I don't have any example, though), but if you want to construct a "theory" based on this idea then it would lack all the proper analytic-functional properties, wouldn't il? (perhaps I misunderstood the question)